# Can't update Juno to Luna - no updates found

Tags: eclipse, windows, updating, eclipse-luna

I've followed these articles: [update eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_update_Eclipse%3F) and [eclipe kepler upgrade](http://codebin.co.uk/blog/upgrading-eclipse-4-3-kepler-to-4-4-luna/).

I've added [this](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna) and [that](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4) repositories and run "Check for updates":

However, I get `no updates found`. How can I update?
P. S. This is on Windows.

Comment: Generally it works better to download a complete new install of new releases

Comment: @greg-449: I can't, I've got a bunch of plugins here I don't want to lose or setup from scratch again. Interestingly enough, I have about the same Eclipse configuration on another computer (also Windows) and updated there no problem. But I can't on this PC, as well as at home.

Comment: I would suggest to make a back up of data and uninstall later install Luna.I am not sure if you can update from Juno to Luna but you can update versions within juno or Luna.

Comment: @Lokesh: as I mentioned in the comment, I have successfully upgraded the same Eclipse configuration on another PC as described in the guide. Also, there is official Eclipse guide on upgrading right there, linked in my question. So it is indeed possible and even intended.

Comment: OOps my bad!!Did not realize.

Comment: So are you on Kepler now, or still Juno?

Comment: @nitind: Juno. It's in the title.